# Why can't I reference a sprite loading variable in a separate class?

Tags: libgdx, architecture

When I reference a sprite I declared in a separate class that I am using to load images and rectangles, I get an error.

Here's how I reference the image in the `render` method:

```
loading.playerSprite.draw(batch);  
loading.wallSprite.draw(batch);
```

Here's where the variable is declared:

```
public Sprite wallSprite;
public Rectangle playerRect, wallRect;
public Sprite playerSprite;

public void player() {
    playerSprite = new Sprite(new Texture("img/player.png"));

    playerRect = new Rectangle(playerSprite.getX(), playerSprite.getY(),
            playerSprite.getWidth(), playerSprite.getHeight());
}

public void Wall() {
    wallSprite = new Sprite(new Texture("img/wall.png"));

    wallRect = new Rectangle(wallSprite.getX(), wallSprite.getY(),
            wallSprite.getWidth(), wallSprite.getHeight());
}
```

Here's the error:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mediocre.game.Screen.PlayScreen.render(PlayScreen.java:33)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:206)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)
```

Its weird that this is failing, because it worked previously, but my hard drive corrupted and I cant remember how I did it before...

Comment: Do you get an NullPointerException error ?

Comment: More details on the error would be useful.

Comment: Yes, sorry i should had included that

Comment: What's a "sprite loading variable"? Do you mean a "loading-sprite variable" as in a variable which is holding a sprite which contains a loading-bar image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created the voids to instantiate the sprites from separate class but you forgot to call them before the `render()` method. Insert `separateClass.player()` and  `separateClass.Wall()` in the `show()` method and it should work.

ps : Do not forget to first start your *separateClass* (`separateClass sClass = new separateClass(parameters)`)

Comment: Thank you soo much, I knew it was going to be something dumb like that!

Comment: You're welcome :) Could you check it as an answer as it resolved your problem ? Thanks.